# IF function for specific text strings

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I am trying to write a formula that takes a word and process it through a IF function in excel, The Values are list in the formula. My issue right now is the fact that I have Large, X-Large and 1X-Large text. The X-Large and 1X-Large are unique strings and need the IF function to be able to differentiate the two.

Here is what i have so far.

```
=if(or(isnumber(search("Small",af2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Medium",AF2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Large",AF2)),,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X-Large",AF2))),"Small",or(isnumber(search("1X-Large",af2)),isnumber(search("2X-Large",af2)),isnumber(search("3X-Large",af2)),isnumber(search("4X-Large",af2))),"1X-Large")
```

I cant understand why it's showing an error and only displays small when it works.

All help is appreciated

Comment: Right now, your formula's only results can be "small" or "1X-Large", is that intended? Can you provide sample data with expected results?

Comment: you can't check for is number you must check for position 1.  Since Large occurs in both X-Large and 1x-Large, the result is 3 or 4 which is a number, but not specific enough.  your check must be if (search("x-large",AF2)=1) anything other than 1 means the text didn't start with that.  This may not be enough either since you need an EXACT match.  you may be better off using `match` instead of  `search`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current formula shouldn't work, it should be giving you an error about having too many arguments. A breakdown of your function:

```
=if(
  or(isnumber(search("Small",af2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Medium",AF2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Large",AF2)),,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X-Large",AF2))),
  "Small",
  or(isnumber(search("1X-Large",af2)),isnumber(search("2X-Large",af2)),isnumber(search("3X-Large",af2)),isnumber(search("4X-Large",af2))),
  "1X-Large"
)
```

You cannot use 4 parameters in an `IF`. You need to have a maximum of 3. Maybe what you meant was:

```
=if(
  or(isnumber(search("Small",af2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Medium",AF2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Large",AF2)),,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X-Large",AF2))),
  "Small",
  IF(
    or(isnumber(search("1X-Large",af2)),isnumber(search("2X-Large",af2)),isnumber(search("3X-Large",af2)),isnumber(search("4X-Large",af2))),
    "1X-Large"
  )
)
```

But that doesn't solve your issue about the `X-Large` part. To cater for that, you can check whether the `X-Large` series exist first, then the others.

```
=IF(
  OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1X-Large",AF2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2X-Large",AF2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("3X-Large",AF2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("4X-Large",AF2))),
  "1X-Large",
  IF(
    OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Small",AF2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Medium",AF2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Large",AF2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X-Large",AF2))),
    "Small"
  )
)
```

Although you can make it shorter with this:

```
=IF(
  OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"1X-Large","2X-Large","3X-Large","4X-Large"},AF2))),
  "1X-Large",
  IF(
    OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Small","Medium","Large","X-Large"},AF2))),
    "Small"
  )
)
```

In one line...

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"1X-Large","2X-Large","3X-Large","4X-Large"},AF2))),"1X-Large",IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Small","Medium","Large","X-Large"},AF2))),"Small"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jerry and everyone else who replied!!

Comment: it did solve it, I just need to sit down and adjust it to the current sheet i'm working with. I am trying to make the spreadsheet creation more efficient.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to work on it at the moment, i will do it at home. I'll post a update then.

Comment: worked like a charm. I now understand why it was throwing out only small. Thanks for everything!

Comment: @eagrubman Please click on the tickmark outline to mark the answer as accepted and at the same time, your question as solved :)

Comment: Thanks again and I have selected the check mark. I was able to write three more formulas because of the correction.